# Need some help to configure my project architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two dependancies on my iOS project.

- The first is named LK, it is a general framework with some features used in ALL my projects (0 dependency).
- The second is named LKS, it is a specific framework containing sharing functions (1 dependency to LK)

**Problem** :
My current project has 2 dependencies (LK and LKS) and LKS has a dependancy with LK.
So I have set the LKS Header Search Path to include LK headers.
But I think it is dirty to do that.

Have you got a better solution to purpose to me to set my project architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's not "dirty" at all. If you are using '#import' Objective-C will keep headers from being included more than once.

If you intend to include LK everywhere you could add it to your 'projectName-Prefix.pch' file.
This will force it to be included in all your projects headers, that way no need to explicitly
include it in LKS.